# returns, standard deviation and mean absolute deviation

Tags: volatility, returns, standard-deviation

I'm trying to understand the relationships between return, standard deviation and mean absolute deviation.

I saw someone mention:

$daily return * 16 \approx annualized volatility$

$weekly return * 7.2 \approx annualized volatility$

$monthly return * 3.5 \approx annualized volatility$

So he assumes the returns are equal to the standard deviation, because:

$\large \sigma_d\sqrt{252} = \sigma_a$

$\large \sigma_w\sqrt{52} = \sigma_a$

$\large \sigma_m\sqrt{12} = \sigma_a$

Is this correct?
Because:

$\large E(|R_t|) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma_t$

Which would result in:

$\large\frac{E(|R_d|)}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}}\sqrt{252} = \sigma_a$

$\large\frac{E(|R_w|)}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}}\sqrt{52} = \sigma_a$

$\large\frac{E(|R_m|)}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}}\sqrt{12} = \sigma_a$

Am I wrong in considering the above mentioned returns as $\large E(|Rt|)$ instead of $\large \sigma_t$ ?

Comment: If you take a single return, square it and multiply by 252 that does indeed give you an estimate of annualized variance, but it is a very poor (noisy) estimate because it is based on a single data point (you need far more data points for a useful estimate). You can also work with absolute values of return(s) instead of squares like you are suggesting and that may indeed have some advantages (and disadvantages).

Comment: The context was that it was meant to be used to compare realized volatility to implied volatility from a day, week or month ago.
 
If you consider daily return equal to sigma you multiply it by +-16 to get annualized volatility but if you consider it absolute returns you multiply by +-20 to get annualized volatility, which is a big difference. So it seems unlikely to me that both methods are correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "if you consider daily return equal to sigma" ? Daily return is a random variable, sigma is the standard deviation of that variable, MAD is a (different) measure of variabilty for that variable. As you point out for a normal dist. sigma and MAD are related by $\sqrt{2/\pi}$. Where is the contradiction?

Comment: If, like in my example, you have 1 observation of return then sigma and mean absolute deviation are equal to eachother (absolute return). No?